# automatic zoom out to fit all?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to tell ggplot2 to zoom out to fit all the elements of a plot? For example, I would like to produce something like the following plot

[image]

I can create this plot by hardcoding `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-8, 8.5))` but I would like a way to determining those values automatically so the code works with any density.

This is my code right now:

```
wrap_sentence <- function(string, width) {
  words <- unlist(strsplit(string, " "))
  fullsentence <- ""
  checklen <- ""
  for(i in 1:length(words)) {
    checklen <- paste(checklen, words[i])
    if(nchar(checklen)>(width+1)) {
      fullsentence <- paste0(fullsentence, "\n")
      checklen <- ""
    }
    fullsentence <- paste(fullsentence, words[i])
  }
  fullsentence <- sub("^\\s", "", fullsentence)
  fullsentence <- gsub("\n ", "\n", fullsentence)
  return(fullsentence)
}


library(ggplot2)
set.seed(02062017)
cutoff <- 0.75
t.text <- "There is a xx% chance that X improves achivement compared to Y"
c.text <- "There is a xx% chance that Y improves achivement compared to X"


df.plot <- data.frame(y = rnorm(n=100, mean = 0.5, sd = 2))

# Greater
ds <- density(df.plot$y, from = cutoff, to = max(df.plot$y))
ds_data <- data.frame(x = ds$x, y = ds$y)
prob_gt <- scales::percent(mean(df.plot[,"y"] > cutoff))

x_gt_end <- (max(df.plot[,"y"])+cutoff)/4
y_gt_end <- (density(df.plot[,"y"], from=x_gt_end, to=x_gt_end, n=1)$y)*2/3

x_gt_start <- (max(df.plot[,"y"])+cutoff)/2
y_start <-(density(df.plot[,"y"], from=x_gt_end, to=x_gt_end, n=1)$y + y_gt_end)/2

gt_y <- density(df.plot[,"y"], from=x_gt_start, to=x_gt_start, n=1)$y

gt_text <- gsub("xx%", prob_gt, t.text)

gt_text <- wrap_sentence(string = gt_text, width = 24)

# Less than

ds_less <- density(df.plot$y, from = min(df.plot$y), to = cutoff)
ds_data_less <- data.frame(x = ds_less$x, y = ds_less$y)
prob_lt <- scales::percent(1-mean(df.plot[,"y"] > cutoff))

x_lt_end <- (min(df.plot[,"y"])+cutoff)/4
y_lt_end <- (density(df.plot[,"y"], from=x_lt_end, to=x_lt_end, n=1)$y)*2/3

x_lt_start <- (min(df.plot[,"y"])+cutoff)/2
y_lt_start <-(density(df.plot[,"y"], from=x_lt_end, to=x_lt_end, n=1)$y + y_lt_end)/2

lt_text <- gsub("xx%", prob_lt, c.text)

lt_text <- wrap_sentence(string = lt_text, width = 24)

ggplot(df.plot, aes(y)) + geom_density() +
  geom_area(data = ds_data,
            aes(x = x, y = y),
            alpha = 0.5,
            fill = "darkblue") +
  geom_area(data = ds_data_less,
            aes(x = x, y = y),
            alpha = 0.5,
            fill = "darkred") +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x_gt_start, y = y_start, xend = x_gt_end, yend = y_gt_end), 
               arrow = arrow(length=unit(0.30,"cm"), type = "closed"), 
               color="darkblue", alpha = 0.5, size=1) + 
  geom_label(aes(x = x_gt_start, y = y_start), label=gt_text, 
             vjust = "outward", hjust = "outward") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x_lt_start, y = y_lt_start, xend = x_lt_end, yend = y_lt_end), 
               arrow = arrow(length=unit(0.30,"cm"), type = "closed"), 
               color="darkred", alpha = 0.5, size=1) + 
  geom_label(aes(x = x_lt_start, y = y_lt_start), label=lt_text, 
             vjust = "outward", hjust = "outward") + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-8, 8.5))
```

Note that if i don't include the hard-coded `coord_cartesian` ggplot will cut out the boxes with the labels.

Comment: Not possible. Ggplot2 doesn't set the plot panel to a specific size but instead lets it stretch to fill the device. Therefore there's no way to prevent text from being too big for the plot panel. You could however set expand_limits to a good guesstimate based on your data and typical device size.

Comment: Could I get the coordinates for the `geom_label` boxes and use that to set `coord_cartesian`? I basically imagine 1. plot and save in object `p`, 2. check object p and extract coordinates from it, 3. `p + coord_cartesian` using data from (2).